# Filling Datagrid And Sql Query

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, oracle10g, pivot, reporting

I have 3 tables in database shown below. And I want to make a report just like shown link below. How can I do it with datagrid or datalist? Which one is the best chois? I have tried to do it for a week.

[image: http://img123.imageshack.us/my.php?image=61519307xx5.jpg]

> **COMPANY**: ID_COMPANY, COMPANY_NAME
>
> **PRODUCT**: ID_PRODUCT, PRODUCT_NAME
>
> **PRODUCT_SALE**: ID_COMPANY, ID_PRODUCT, SALE_COUNT

**Updated** :

I could do it, with your helps. However Now I have a small problem too.

When I write query with pivot, products' name become column header. if a product name's length is bigger than 30 character, Oracle don't accept it as a column header. So I have croped and make the product names 30 character to solve this problem. After that a problem occured too.

When I crop product name as 30 character, some products become same name and "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined" error message occured.

In this case what can be done?

Comment: is there a finite number of either companies or products?

Comment: if you want more answers, make the title a little clearer (Datagrid, Sql, Dynamic Columns)

Comment: I update your both answers in your actual question and recommend to delete answers. So site will be nit and clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a standard sql query (pivots are expensive in terms of performance) and create a custom pivot function in your server side code. Here are a couple of examples.

```
''' <summary>
''' Pivots columnX as new columns for the X axis (must be unique values) and the remaining columns as 
''' the Y axis. Optionally can include columns to exclude from the Y axis.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="dt"></param>
''' <param name="columnX"></param>
''' <param name="columnsToIgnore"></param>
''' <returns>DataTable</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function Pivot(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal columnX As String, ByVal ParamArray columnsToIgnore As String()) As DataTable

    Dim dt2 As New DataTable()

    If columnX = "" Then
        columnX = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
    End If

    'Add a Column at the beginning of the table 
    dt2.Columns.Add(columnX)

    'Read all DISTINCT values from columnX Column in the provided DataTable 
    Dim columnXValues As New List(Of String)()

    'Create the list of columns to ignore 
    Dim listColumnsToIgnore As New List(Of String)()
    If columnsToIgnore.Length > 0 Then
        listColumnsToIgnore.AddRange(columnsToIgnore)
    End If

    If Not listColumnsToIgnore.Contains(columnX) Then
        listColumnsToIgnore.Add(columnX)
    End If

    ' Add the X axis columns
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim columnXTemp As String = dr(columnX).ToString()
        If Not columnXValues.Contains(columnXTemp) Then
            columnXValues.Add(columnXTemp)
            dt2.Columns.Add(columnXTemp)
        Else
            Throw New Exception("The inversion used must have unique values for column " + columnX)
        End If
    Next

    'Add a row for each non-columnX of the DataTable 
    For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        If Not columnXValues.Contains(dc.ColumnName) AndAlso Not listColumnsToIgnore.Contains(dc.ColumnName) Then
            Dim dr As DataRow = dt2.NewRow()
            dr(0) = dc.ColumnName
            dt2.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If
    Next

    'Complete the datatable with the values 
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt2.Rows.Count - 1
        For j As Integer = 1 To dt2.Columns.Count - 1
            dt2.Rows(i)(j) = dt.Rows(j - 1)(dt2.Rows(i)(0).ToString()).ToString()
        Next
    Next

    Return dt2

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Can pivot any column as X, any column as Y, and any column as Z. Sort on X, sort on Y and optionally, the 
''' values at the intersection of x and y (Z axis) can be summed.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="dt"></param>
''' <param name="columnX"></param>
''' <param name="columnY"></param>
''' <param name="columnZ"></param>
''' <param name="nullValue"></param>
''' <param name="sumValues"></param>
''' <param name="xSort"></param>
''' <param name="ySort"></param>
''' <returns>DataTable</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function Pivot(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal columnX As String, ByVal columnY As String, ByVal columnZ As String, _
    ByVal nullValue As String, ByVal sumValues As Boolean, ByVal xSort As Sort, ByVal ySort As Sort) As DataTable

    Dim dt2 As New DataTable()
    Dim tickList As List(Of Long) = Nothing

    If columnX = "" Then
        columnX = dt.Columns(0).ColumnName
    End If

    'Add a Column at the beginning of the table 
    dt2.Columns.Add(columnY)

    'Read all DISTINCT values from columnX Column in the provided DataTable 
    Dim columnXValues As New List(Of String)()
    Dim cols As Integer = 0

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If dr(columnX).ToString.Contains("'") Then
            dr(columnX) = dr(columnX).ToString.Replace("'", "")
        End If
        If Not columnXValues.Contains(dr(columnX).ToString) Then
            'Read each row value, if it's different from others provided, 
            'add to the list of values and creates a new Column with its value. 
            columnXValues.Add(dr(columnX).ToString)
        End If
    Next

    'Sort X if needed
    If Not xSort = Sort.None Then
        columnXValues = SortValues(columnXValues, xSort)
    End If

    'Add columnX
    For Each s As String In columnXValues
        dt2.Columns.Add(s)
    Next

    'Verify Y and Z Axis columns were provided 
    If columnY <> "" AndAlso columnZ <> "" Then
        'Read DISTINCT Values for Y Axis Column 
        Dim columnYValues As New List(Of String)()

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            If dr(columnY).ToString.Contains("'") Then
                dr(columnY) = dr(columnY).ToString.Replace("'", "")
            End If
            If Not columnYValues.Contains(dr(columnY).ToString()) Then
                columnYValues.Add(dr(columnY).ToString())
            End If
        Next

        ' Now we can sort the Y axis if needed. 
        If Not ySort = Sort.None Then
            columnYValues = SortValues(columnYValues, ySort)
        End If

        'Loop all Distinct ColumnY Values
        For Each columnYValue As String In columnYValues
            'Create a new Row 
            Dim drReturn As DataRow = dt2.NewRow()
            drReturn(0) = columnYValue
            Dim rows As DataRow() = dt.[Select](columnY + "='" + columnYValue + "'")

            'Read each row to fill the DataTable 
            For Each dr As DataRow In rows
                Dim rowColumnTitle As String = dr(columnX).ToString()

                'Read each column to fill the DataTable 
                For Each dc As DataColumn In dt2.Columns
                    If dc.ColumnName = rowColumnTitle Then
                        'If sumValues, try to perform a Sum 
                        'If sum is not possible due to value types, use the nullValue string
                        If sumValues Then
                            If IsNumeric(dr(columnZ).ToString) Then
                                drReturn(rowColumnTitle) = Val(drReturn(rowColumnTitle).ToString) + Val(dr(columnZ).ToString)
                            Else
                                drReturn(rowColumnTitle) = nullValue
                            End If
                        Else
                            drReturn(rowColumnTitle) = dr(columnZ).ToString
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            dt2.Rows.Add(drReturn)

        Next
    Else
        Throw New Exception("The columns to perform inversion are not provided")
    End If

    'if nullValue param was provided, fill the datable with it 
    If nullValue <> "" Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt2.Rows
            For Each dc As DataColumn In dt2.Columns
                If dr(dc.ColumnName).ToString() = "" Then
                    dr(dc.ColumnName) = nullValue
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If

    Return dt2

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Sorts a list of strings checking to see if they are numeric or date types.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="list"></param>
''' <param name="srt"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Shared Function SortValues(ByVal list As List(Of String), ByVal srt As Sort) As List(Of String)

    Dim tickList As List(Of Long) = Nothing
    Dim dblList As List(Of Double) = Nothing

    ' Figure out how to sort columnX
    For Each s As String In list
        Dim colDate As Date = Nothing
        If Date.TryParse(s, colDate) Then
            tickList = New List(Of Long)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Dim dateTicks As Long

    If Not tickList Is Nothing Then
        For Each s As String In list
            dateTicks = DateTime.Parse(s).Ticks
            If Not tickList.Contains(dateTicks) Then
                tickList.Add(dateTicks)
            End If
        Next

        If srt = Sort.DESC Then
            tickList.Sort()
            tickList.Reverse()
        ElseIf srt = Sort.ASC Then
            tickList.Sort()
        End If

        list.Clear()
        For Each lng As Long In tickList
            list.Add(New Date(lng).ToString("G"))
        Next
    Else
        Dim dbl As Double = Nothing

        For Each s As String In list
            If IsNumeric(s) Then
                dblList = New List(Of Double)
            End If
        Next

        If Not dblList Is Nothing Then
            'Doubles or Integers
            For Each s As String In list
                dbl = Val(s)
                If Not dblList.Contains(dbl) Then
                    dblList.Add(dbl)
                End If
            Next

            If srt = Sort.DESC Then
                dblList.Sort()
                dblList.Reverse()
            ElseIf srt = Sort.ASC Then
                dblList.Sort()
            End If

            list.Clear()
            For Each d As Double In dblList
                list.Add(d.ToString)
            Next
        Else
            'Strings
            If srt = Sort.DESC Then
                list.Sort()
                list.Reverse()
            ElseIf srt = Sort.ASC Then
                list.Sort()
            End If
        End If

    End If

    Return list

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of SQL are you running?  Using PIVOT might be a quick way to get the data into the form you want, and then you can use the generic DataGrid to just display the data in it's (almost) "raw" form - that is, the way the data is presented by the SQL server.  You could then think of the DataGrid more like a spreadsheet than representative of a data table as found in a database.

Here's a good starter document for how to use PIVOT to represent the data in the form you're after:

```
http://www.tsqltutorials.com/pivot.php
```

Of course, I think this might only be available in SQL 2005... so if you're running an older version this may be no help.

**Updated :**

On Oracle 10g you're going to need the MODEL extension, it's not a *world* different than PIVOT in SQL but obviously Oracle 10g does things its own way: [Check this link](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/300/pivoting-in-sql-using-the-10g-model-clause)

Comment: You are gave 2 answers, I updated with your first answer and recommend second to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Following will work if product numbers are static:

```
<asp:gridview>
    <columns>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="companyname" itemstyle-headertext="" />
        <asp:boundfield datafield="SALE_COUNT" itemstyle-headertext='<%# FunctionToLoadurproduct(product1) %>' />
        <asp:boundfield datafield="SALE_COUNT" itemstyle-headertext='<%# FunctionToLoadurproduct(product1) %>' />

        and so on...
    </columns>
</gridview >
```

Manage the product sales according to the product id in your query using inline queries.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a crosstab report to me. You have 2 options to go about this

1. Pivot the data in the database and bind that to a datagrid. The exact syntax of doing this will vary based on the database engine you're using. [Here's an example in SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/)
2. Use a reporting tool that can do cross tabs based on a simple join, like SQL Reporting Services, Crystal Reports, XtraReports, etc

Answer (score 1):

On Oracle 10g you're going to need the MODEL extension, it's not a *world* different than PIVOT in SQL but obviously Oracle 10g does things its own way:

http://technology.amis.nl/blog/300/pivoting-in-sql-using-the-10g-model-clause

Answer (score 0):

Use nested Repeaters Control. The outer repeater will repeat Companies and the inner will repeat Products.